# How to write Batch Script to Change Directory to WILDCARD folder based on user input in order to copy a

Tags: batch-file, directory, wildcard

I want to be able to copy the zip file over from a folder that will sit on desktop. The folder will have a different name every week. We will process it and delete it. I want to be able to use a user input to find any folder on my desktop that has that name in it. Once found, I want to be able to go into that folder and copy the zip file that is in there to a folder called PROCESSED LINKFILES. Here is the script. The first part works fine but I can't get the the user input to find the correct folder by using the wildcard feature * . Please help:

### usermessage.vbs

```
ECHO WScript.Echo InputBox( "Please Enter the name of the store", "Store Name", "" )
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('CSCRIPT.EXE //NoLogo usermessage.vbs') DO SET StoreName=%%A
ECHO Store Name is %StoreName%
DEL usermessage.vbs


copy C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\*%StoreName%*\*.zip C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\PROCESSED_LINKFILES
```

Comment: You can't use a wildcard in two parts of the path. First do a `cd C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\*%StoreName%*` and then do the `copy *.zip C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\PROCESSED_LINKFILES`

Comment: I have already tried this. It says the directory is invalid. If for example, I input the name APPLE, then it will say: C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\*APPLE* is an invalid directory. In other words, it treats the * as a character rather than a wildcard.

Comment: Work for me! `C:\Documents and Settings\Test>`_dir /b_ `Folder One Name` `Folder Three Name` `Folder Two Name` `C:\Documents and Settings\Test>`_cd *two*_ `C:\Documents and Settings\Test\Folder Two Name`. Windows XP 5.1.2600 here. Perhaps you missed a \ between `Desktop` and `*%StoreName%*`?

Answer (score 0):

read `HELP FOR` and then try at the command line this double `FOR` loop

```
for /d %d in (\temp\f*) do @for %f in (%d\f*) do @echo %f
```

as you see, it will loop over all the f* folders and for each of them if will loop over all the f* files.

So, adapting this simple strategy to your requirements and giving it an appropiate BAT syntax, you may begin trying this...

```
@echo off
set storename=%1
set myfolder=C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\
set dstfolder=%myfolder%\PROCESSED_FILES
set myfiles=*.zip
for /d %%d in (%myfolder%\*%storename%*) do (
  for %%f in (%%d\%myfiles%) do (
    echo copy %%f %dstfolder%
  )
)
```

test carefully before removing the `ECHO`

Comment: @echo off
set storename=%1
set myfolder=C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\Desktop\
set dstfolder=%myfolder%\PROCESSED_FILES
set myfiles=*.zip
for /d %%d in (%myfolder%\*%storename%*) do (
  for %%f in (%%d\%myfiles%) do (
    echo copy %%f %dstfolder%
  )
)

Comment: It doesn't work. When I checked my Processed Files folder where I expected to see zip file, it is empty.